# Automatically call a task every 5 seconds

Tags: c#, infragistics

i have an Infragistics carousel control which i want to call "next" on every 5 seconds. However im not sure how to do this without a while true.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Currently its kicked off from a click, starting a task within a while true. Obviously this i what i want to avoid.

```
 private void GoToNext(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        while (true)
        {


            Task task = new Task(() => MyCarousel.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new next(goToNext), null));
            task.Start();

        }

    }

private bool goToNext()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(15);
        MyCarousel.ExecuteCommand(Infragistics.Windows.Controls.XamCarouselPanelCommands.NavigateToNextItem);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timers are used for this in general, sitting in the background and triggering every so often. There are a number in .NET (in System.Timers and elsewhere) and which one is best depends on your particular scenario.